# Application is not offered for "Sony Xperia T2 Ultra" device from Google Play Store

Tags: android, sony-xperia

My application is not offered on "Sony Xperia T2 Ultra". Filtering logic with my AndroidManifest is as follows:

```
<uses-sdk 
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />

<uses-configuration android:reqTouchScreen="finger"/>
<uses-configuration android:reqTouchScreen="stylus"/>

 <compatible-screens>
      <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
      <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
      <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
      <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="480" />
      <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="640" />
  <!-- all normal size screens -->
      <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
      <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
      <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
      <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
      <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
      <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="640" />
  <!-- partial large size screens -->
      <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Please suggest what might be the potential issues those block the application to be get offered on the device.

Comment: what is the `OS Version, API level, screenDensity` of `Sony Xperia T2 Ultra`? Check if these settings of device match the ones you have set on `AndroidManifest`

Comment: Try removing the `<uses-configuration android:reqTouchScreen="stylus"/>
` and re-installing.

Comment: I assume you verified that it is available on other devices?

Comment: @hrskra- ScreenDensity of Sony-T2 is not found any where? I have the same thinking that this might be the issue. But not sure. If any one now the right value, i can try that.

Comment: @George: Side installation is not has the problem. And also <uses-configuration android:reqTouchScreen="stylus"/> is working fine for other devices. Is there any specific behind this suggestion?

Comment: @AmitJain No. Just simple brute-force divide and conquer problem solving. I do not know about the setup of the `T2` device but the stylus support seemed suspicious.

Comment: Not an issue. But looks that is not the problem here.